# Cakephp: Displaying profile pictures for users in cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Hie guys i am still learning cakephp so this question might be easy but im struggling. I have a view.ctp that is currently displaying a buyer's profile like personal details, in addition to this i also want it to display a profile picture for the buyer as well. I have a field in the buyers table called prof_pic which is using longblob data type. I can view the profile of the logged buyer, now i want them to view their profile picture and the personal details as well. How do i do this? Thank you

Comment: http://edivad.wordpress.com/2007/04/17/cakephp-mysql-and-blob/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider saving your files in the filesystem instead of the database. Florian Krämer from CakeDC did a nice [writeup](http://cakedc.com/florian_kraemer/2010/01/25/file-uploading-file-storage-and-cakephp-mediaview-class) of why to do this. In short:

> Storing files in the database is in nearly all cases a bad solution
>   because when you get the file it has to go its way through the
>   database connection, which can, specially on servers that are not in
>   the same network, cause performance problems.
>
> Advantages of storage in the file system:
>
> 1. Easy and direct file access, to parse them (csv, xml...) or manipulate them (images)
> 2. You don't need to install any additional software to manage them
> 3. Easy to move and mount on other machines
> 4. Smaller then stored in a DB

He started an interesting [implementation](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/) of a plugin to do this. It makes use of the [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette) filesystem abstraction layer and makes working with files in Cake much cleaner. A way to scale Images to your needs with the [Imagine](https://github.com/cakedc/imagine) plugin is also already provided and you're even able to host your images on Amazon S3 and the likes if you're running a high traffic site.

Answer (score 1):

save image in folder

then you can easily use it ... resize or crop as you like ..

that's simple and easy way  :)